# Does Haruka ever get tired?

Tags: yakuza-3

I just picked up Yakuza 3 and at the very beginning of the game there is a segment where you wander around Kamurocho with Haruka with the goal of letting her have a good time by visiting various restaurants/attractions.

Eventually, you're supposed to leave her at Emoto's clinic so that you can go somewhere on your own and advance the plot, but whenever you try and leave her there she says she wants to hang out with you some more.

While you can always politely refuse, I wonder, does she ever get tired and straight out agree to stay at the clinic for a while?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on my experience later in the game, when she would catch up with me after I effectively ditched her, and she'd be breathing really hard, I'd say no, that girl never seems to really get tired.

Seriously, if it's possible to max out her trust at that point in the game, and complete any side stories that require her to start, that *might* trigger it. But from what I've seen she's more than happy to walk around with you, and find things to do, as long as you let her.

(Since people who have played the first/second seem to like Haruka, requiring you to say goodbye might be setup that way to trigger an emotional feeling. Or just to keep you guessing. Am I going to miss something if I say goodbye now? Should I walk around town just *one* more time?)

Comment: You make the possibility of her getting tired seem highly unlikely, and since I doubt anyone has anything more conclusive to say, I'll gladly take your answer.

Comment: Thanks. Although I'll admit I'm now curious whether maxing out her trust (again, assuming that's possible) impacts it ... :D